# Count Number of Distinct Columns in a Row with tSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing a task for my work and unfortunately the tables are designed horribly and I can't do too much as far as modifying the structure (one of our major programs here has been based off these outdated tables for years).  That being said, I need to find a way to use SQL Server (TSQL) to count the number of distinct columns in a given row.

#### Example:

I have a table with columns `name`, `fieldA`, `fieldB`, `fieldC`, `fieldD`, etc
I want to return a table with each of the rows, returning `name` and the number of distinct columns for `fieldA` - `fieldD`

#### Visually:

- Jim - 1 - 3 - 4 - 6
- John - 1 - 1 - 1 - 2
- Jane 2 - 2 - 3 - 3

Would return

- Jim - 4
- John - 2
- Jane - 2

Comment: Are the fields actually integer values?

Comment: no, they are varchars

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this is by unpivoting the data and then subsequently grouping it again.  This gives you the ability to use `count(distinct)`:

```
select name, count(distinct val)
from t
unpivot (val for col in (FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD)) unpvt
group by name;
```

However, the most efficient way to do this is to keep all the processing on a single row -- no `join`s or `group by`s or `union`s.  Assuming none of the values are `NULL`, the following works for 4 columns:

```
select name,
       4 - ((case when FieldA in (FieldB, FieldC, FieldD) then 1 else 0 end) +
            (case when FieldB in (FieldC, FieldD) then 1 else 0 end) +
            (case when FieldC in (FieldD) then 1 else 0 end)
           )
from t;
```

That is, start with the total count of columns.  Then subtract 1 each time a column is like a column that comes *later*.  This last condition ensures that duplicates are not counted more than once.

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE
(
  Name VARCHAR(32),
  A VARCHAR(32),
  B VARCHAR(32),
  C VARCHAR(32),
  D VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT @x VALUES
('Jim', 1,3,4,6),
('John',1,1,1,2),
('Jane',2,2,3,3);

SELECT Name, NumCols = COUNT(DISTINCT x) 
FROM @x AS x
UNPIVOT (x FOR y IN (A,B,C,D)) AS up
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY NumCols DESC;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UNPIVOT` operator to turn columns to rows and then count distinct values:

```
select c_name
     , count(distinct val) as distinct_vals
     , count(val)          as total_vals
  from ( select c_name
              , val
           from t1
         unpivot(
             val for col in(col1, col2, col3, col4) 
          ) unpvt
        ) s
group by c_name
```

result:

```
C_NAME  DISTINCT_VALS   TOTAL_VALS
Jane    2               4
Jim     4               4
John    2               4
```

[**SQLFIDDLE Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3d12/11)

Answer (score 4):

Yet another method:

```
SELECT
   Name,
   Cnt = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT V) FROM (VALUES (A), (B), (C), (D)) AS v (V))
FROM atable
;
```

That uses SQL Server 2008 syntax (the `VALUES` row constructor). It can be adapted for earlier versions by replacing the `VALUES (A), (B), ...` with `SELECT A UNION ALL SELECT B UNION ALL ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Name,Count(*) From
(select Name,FieldA from test10
Union
select Name,FieldB from test10
union
select Name,FieldC from test10
Union
select Name,FieldD from test10)as a
Group by name
```